# How to generate RSA public key as PKCS#1

Tags: php, encryption

This will create RSA keys and a public key in SPKI format. How to output public key in pkcs#1 format?

```
class Asymmetric {
    protected $private_key;
    
    const KEY_BITS          = 4096;
    const DIGEST_ALGORITHM  = 'SHA512';
    const ENCRYPT_PADDING   = OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING;
    const SIGN_ALGORITHM    = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA512;
    
    public function generate_keys(): array{
        $resource = openssl_pkey_new([
            'digest_alg'        => self::DIGEST_ALGORITHM,
            'private_key_bits'  => self::KEY_BITS,
            'private_key_type'  => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
        ]);
        
        openssl_pkey_export($resource, $this->private_key);
        
        return [
            $this->private_key,
            openssl_pkey_get_details($resource)['key']
        ];
    }
}
```

And how to load a public key as PKCS#1 here? The function only supports SPKI formats

```
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $ciphertext, $this->public_key, Asymmetric::ENCRYPT_PADDING);
```

Comment: See Michaela's note: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php#101513

Comment: It is more reliable to use a library that supports PKCS#1 format, e.g. [phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa).

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need a PKCS#1 formatted public key if the function you want to use only supports the more common SPKI form? Is this true anyway? `this->public_key` points to a structure in memory, right? Encoding generally happens when exporting.